Are 21% of American adults illiterate?
The National Literacy Institute makes the claim.

Literacy Data and its impact on the Nation

Illiteracy has become such a serious problem in our country that 130 million adults are now unable to read a simple story to their children
21% of adults in the US are illiterate in 2022
54% of adults have a literacy below 6th grade level


That seems impossible, given the demands of a modern society.
Note that this question asks about current adults, not about educating children.

@Oddthinking I actually liked "literally illiterate". As an aside, it slightly alters the meaning of the question: The PIAAC definition establishes a threshold that allows participation; individuals below that threshold may still be able to read in principal (i.e., one might say they are not literally illiterate) but are not able to put the contents to work.

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/20739/will-1-in-4-american-children-grow-up-illiterate?noredirect=1&lq=1 I still think it's a duplicate, but I didn't know I could close questions on my own, so I reopened.

@DavePhD It might be. Here's the question: Have things evolved in 10 years? That's a ½ a generation. (Not to mention that both question and answer references do not work or are out of date.)  This maybe a question for meta.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica: The original claim didn't include "literally illiterate". The definition of illiteracy we should be using is that of the claimant (ideally with an explanation if that definition is misleading to lay people). That said, looking at the source, I can't see anywhere they have defined it.

The so-called National Literacy Institute is some sort of commercial provider of "professional development workshops" whose front page says "Discovering Our Future of Education through the Lenses of Artificial Intelligence and its potential impact on education and the wider world" (capitalization theirs). They have a blog with 3 posts of which this is one. This doesn't appear to be a notable claim.

Yes and no, depends on your definition
CIA World Factbook states:

There are no universal definitions and standards of literacy.

Yes, 21% of American adults are illiterate:
The Institute of Education Sciences (IES) defines literacy

PIAAC defines literacy as “the ability to understand, evaluate, use and engage with written texts to participate in society, to achieve one’s goals, and to develop one’s knowledge and potential” (p. 61, OECD 2013).

The Institute of Education Sciences (IES)  reports:

Four in five U.S. adults (79 percent)
have English literacy skills sufficient to
complete tasks that require comparing
and contrasting information, paraphrasing,
or making low-level inferences—literacy
skills at level 2 or above in PIAAC (OECD
2013). In contrast, one in five U.S. adults
(21 percent) has difficulty completing
these tasks

No, far fewer than 21% of American adults are illiterate:
United Nations uses different definition of (il)literacy

(i) A person is literate who can with understanding both read and write a short simple statement related to his/her everyday life.
(ii) A person is functionally literate who can engage in all those activities in which literacy is required for effective functioning of his/her group and community and also for enabling him/her to continue to use reading, writing and calculation for his/her own and the community’s development.

Under this definition you get 99% by worldpopulationreview.com

Ah, this makes sense. The definition of literacy used is quite broad and mixed with (other, general) cognitive skills. In my naive thinking, "illiterate" means "Latin script looks to them like Chinese script to me". For example, a "literally illiterate" person could not read station names in the subway.

"Four in five U.S. adults (79 percent) have English" If you only consider English, that's totally changing the issue.   Especially if you include Puerto Rico.

@DavePhD Yes. Quote "option to be interviewed in English or Spanish, followed by a skills assessment in English. Because the
skills assessment was conducted only in English, all U.S. PIAAC literacy results are for English literacy" /quote

@DavePhD especially as the US has no official national language (despite what many people think) despite the de facto national language at federal level being English (and in some southern communities Spanish being a strong second). So I can live in the US as a Dutch person and be highly skilled in Dutch and German without knowing a word of English. I'd be functionally illiterate in English despite being fully literate in more languages than most US citizens.

Is the 99% at the end for the basic "literate" definition? Does the cited source have any figures for "functionally literate", which seems to be closer to the PIAAC definition?

The answer could also be improved by explaining who some of these parties are - what does PIAAC stand for? Is the Institute of Education Sciences an independent academic institution, or...? What UN body is being quoted (as I understand it, very little is actually written by "the UN" as a monolithic organisation)?

@DavePhD Puerto Rico is going to change numbers, at most, by just under 1%, as that's their share of the US population.

@pinegulf This answer really needs to be edited to mention that part about the test being based on assessments solely in English. This completely changes the answer and is likely responsible for most if not almost all of the difference between the measured numbers. As of 2023, only 78% of Americans spoke primarily English in their homes. It's more than a bit misleading to say that someone who can read and write fluently in, say, Spanish or Chinese but not English is "illiterate." "Illiterate in English" != "illiterate."

@reirab what do you suggest? I literally quote "Four in five U.S. adults (79 percent) have English literacy skills ..."

@pinegulf Yeah, I missed that the first time I read it, but I do think it would be very helpful to explicitly mention outside the quotes the difference between the claim asked about in the question ("21% of adults in the US are illiterate") and what the source actually provided evidence for (21% of adults don't meet their definition of literacy specifically in English in a country where 22% of people don't speak English as the primary language in their home.) Just to explicitly point out the difference between what is claimed and what's there's actual evidence for.

@reirab and that really makes me wonder how literacy statistics are taken in countries where there is more than one official language. For example, does one have to pass literacy tests in both English and French to be considered literate in Canada or would passing in one language constitute proof of literacy? If one can read and write only in French but lives in Vancouver, where French is not commonly spoken on the street, is one therefore deemed illiterate? What about India, which has like a dozen official languages? If I can only read and write in three of them, am I illiterate?

@RobertColumbia I would assume that most of them measure literacy in at least one language for determining literacy statistics... which is why the claim in the question is very misleading without explicitly specifying that that's not what they're measuring for purposes of their claim. The percentage of Americans who are literate in English can be a useful statistic for some purposes, but it is certainly not equivalent to the literacy rate in the U.S.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica  As a stared in perplexity at a Chinese text bus timetable in outer Shenzhen a Chinese man approached me and showed my how to use and read it. I still can't read the characters but if I have the names in Chinese of where I am and where I am going I can now catch a bus that takes me there and know when it should arrive at my stop and at the destination. Probably :-) .
I can navigate around Beijing on foor with a city map. With quite some effort - as translations to English are informal and differ on each occasion. Can be done solely in Chinese but much much harder.

@reirab Well, a person reading Chinese fluently may still be "functionally illiterate" in America, i.e., unable to use written information for everyday tasks, such as filling out a form or understanding a workplace instruction. Since this is what "functional literacy" as used by the OECD measures, it makes sense to perform the test in English (in America; in China it would make sense to perform it in Chinese, of course, and I would indeed be functionally illiterate there -- one of the 4% unable to take the test).

@Peter-ReinstateMonica There are parts of America where English isn't even the most commonly-spoken language, though... and a lot of the non-English-literate people live in those places. That's kind of like saying half of Hong Kong is illiterate because they don't speak Mandarin or a lot of Geneva is illiterate because they don't speak Swiss German. Like I said, measuring English literacy in the U.S. can be useful for some purposes, but it shouldn't be stated as the "literacy rate" without further qualification.

To make things even more fun, Historians typically define it as "Lives in a society that has and makes use of a writing system." While this is technically a much more generous definition, people get really upset when you refer to their ancient geographical forbearers as "illiterate".

The site making the claim (from the "National Literacy Institute" which appears to be a commercial entity offering courses and coaching) does not provide sources. But the numbers align with the results of the PIAAC OECD study conducted 2012-2014. The U.S. government published the U.S. results from that study. The PIAAC definition for "literacy" is functional: Can people in principle read (i.e., form words from letters); AND do they understand the text, AND  can they put the contents to work. They define the minimum skills for functional literacy as literacy level 2, which includes

making matches between the text and information
paraphrasing
making low-level inferences.

By contrast, somebody who can only perform level 1 tasks, such as

read relatively short continuous, noncontinuous, or mixed texts in digital or print format to locate a single piece of information
enter personal information into a document
recognize basic vocabulary
determine the meaning of sentences
read paragraphs of text

is still illiterate according to the definition used.
I understand the usefulness of this definition, and it reflects recent changes in the assessment of math skills. But I personally would not call somebody who can read a paragraph of text and determine the meaning of a sentence illiterate.1
That somebody cannot make sense of what they read or cannot make inferences may be for any of a myriad of reasons; but they can read.
The share of people who cannot read a paragraph of text or understand a sentence is between 4% and 8%, depending on how many of the 4% of the PIAAC participants who could not be assessed "because of a language barrier or a cognitive or physical inability to be interviewed" actually cannot read.
With respect to the "demands of a modern society": Functional literacy is indeed strongly correlated with economic and social success. Many prison inmates and welfare recipients have below-par reading skills.

1 The authors of a large German literacy study acknowledged that using the word "illiteracy" for people who actually have basic reading skills is both confusing to the lay audience, impairs international cooperation and puts a stigma on that group. They use "adults of low literacy":

Der Begriff „funktionaler Analphabetismus“ gilt als stigmatisierend und als ungeeignet für die erwachsenbildnerische
Praxis. Zudem hat die Erfahrung
seit der LEO – Level-One Studie gezeigt, dass
der Begriff missverständlich, da sehr stark erklärungsbedürftig
und zudem in der internationalen
Diskussion schwer anschlussfähig ist (vgl. Steuten
2014). Um diesem Umstand gerecht zu werden,
verwendet LEO 2018 den Begriff „geringe Literalität“ bzw. „gering literalisierte Erwachsene“


As discussed in comments on the other answer, aside from the exact definition of "literacy" being used, it's also very important to note that 79% number was based on assessments solely in English, while only 78% of Americans primarily speak English at home. The original claim seems to be conflating "illiterate" with "illiterate in English," which are two very different things.

Equating literacy with simple reading is the entire point and problem. "They can read" some sentences, great, that doesn't make them literate by any reasonable use of the word, or we would just talk about reading directly.

@Nij Well, "reasonable" is in the eye of the beholder. Apart from that, we agree.

@Nij that's right. The problem is that the specific requirements for being found literate are elusive and contextual. If a trained medical doctor with no background in law were to find themselves in a third-year law school classroom and expected to read with understanding all of the nuances of a commercial shipping contract, then they will probably experience the negative effects of illiteracy (frustration and eventually course failure) even though they could probably pass a high school or even college-level reading test.

But that's not how (functional) literacy is defined in any reasonable sense, so it's irrelevant. Being functionally literate doesn't require being perfect at all use of language in all contexts.

@Nij - I don't think defining people who can "read a paragraph of text and determine the meaning of a sentence" as illiterate is a reasonable sense. It's good for stigmatizing people with intellectual disabilities and confusing international comparisons, maybe.

Cool, why are you @ing me about that? Nobody has yet mentioned read a paragraph of text and determine the meaning of a sentence as either reasonable or unreasonable in these comments, as a criteria for (functional) literacy. And I have only rejected the vague simple "they can read" definition as not sufficient, and "can read a complex technical document" as excessive.

@Nij I suppose you wanted to address Obie. But because you said that the narrow definition of illiteracy is not reasonable it seemed that you endorsed the one used by PIAAC which was used instead.
